# pouchDB prefix search does not work when _ID is combination of string and number

Tags: pouchdb

Example doc_id: "foo_1451984426790" // combination of string + getTime()

```
var options = {
    include_docs:true, 
    descending:true,
    startkey: "foo_",
    endkey: "foo_\uffff";
};          
db.allDocs(options, function(err, res) {
    // 0 rows are returned.                     
});
```

With the above example code, I get 0 results. I tried a lot of combinations before asking here, and the only thing that does work is a workaround of adding a type property to my 'foo' doc, and after returning allDocs checking:

```
if(type === 'foo') 
    console.log('okay you are foo');
else if(type === 'bar')
    console.log('okay you are bar');
...
```

So the problem I have under the hood is having a different document type because there is one "config" document with _id === 'config', then there are a few of these 'special' docs per DB, but the rest of the docs are the ones which are used to render UI with that data.

In short, 2 approaches i had:

1. prefix the _id and fetch the right docs on the db itself
2. fetch all docs, and if-else a property inside

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I solved this just using a type property in the DB record and checking if it is the right type in the callback. However I am more of an SQL person and used to do that kind of checking on the database instead of in the app itself. Along the way I also transformed an existing query() call to use a persistent view (design doc), per de docs that is a lot faster and better.